# Xcode 5.1: Remove x86_64 architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, x86-64, xcode5.1

In Xcode 5.1 how to remove architecture x86_64?

Project worked fine with Xcode 5.0 but giving linker error in Xcode 5.1. I don't see updated sdk from small bet. So decided to remove architecture x86_64. How can I achieve this in Xcode 5.1?

Screenshot:
[image]

Xcode Architecture Screenshot:
[image]

**UPDATES:** 
Solved problem!

Click on Architecture->Other->Type $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`

Like this image.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove 64-bit arm64 from Target / Build Settings / Architectures / Valid Architectures

Doble click in Valid Architectures, select arm64 and press -

EDIT, Added image:

[image]

Comment: In Xcode 5.1 not show Valid architecture...By default it take armv64 as shown in above image.

Comment: I added an screenshot, it is from Xcode 5.1, and, yes it have Valid Architectures.

Comment: yes, see it in other project but not with this..something wrong. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: +1'd for the information dense screenshot, nice work.